# How does Postgres support rollback without undo logs

Tags: postgresql, transactions

I was going through this [link](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-a-relational-database-work/) and it is mentioned that PostgreSQL does not support undo log. So I am wondering how PostgreSQL rollback a transaction without undo log.

Comment: https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/well-known-databases-use-different-approaches-mvcc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a row is updated or deleted in PostgreSQL, it is not *really* updated or deleted. The old row version just remains in the table and is marked as removed by a certain transaction. That makes an update much like a delete of the old and insert of the new row version.

To roll back a transaction is nothing but to mark the transaction as aborted. Then the old row version automatically becomes the current row version again, without a need for undoing anything.

The Achilles' heel of this technique is that data modifications produce “dead row versions”, which have to be reclaimed later by a background procedure called “vacuuming”.